# Database Schema for a Gym Exercise Log App

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I am making an android app (my first) to record gym workouts but I am not sure on how to best structure the database for storing this data.

I want to be able to store:

- A list of exercises and their properties
- A list of workouts and their properties (containing exercises)
- A list of logged workouts (workout and date of workout)
- All the set data from each logged workout (exercise, number of sets, weight of each set, reps of each set)

I have drawn up the following schema for how I thought this could be implemented:

[image]

My main questions are:

- Is it optimal to store all the individual set log data in a single table (Log Entries)?
- Should the Exercise Type and Equipment tables be separate or just columns in the Exercise Table? Same goes for Workout Type
- Would this be a good approach in terms of performance/usability?

Thanks!

Comment: Why separate tables for Log and Log Entry?

Comment: I wanted there to be a record of the date certain workouts were done, i.e  to be able to scroll through a calendar view and see I did workout X on day Y.


Would it be better just to have workout_id in the log entries table and query that table for the dates workouts were done?

Comment: Then I guess the schema is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it optimal to store all the individual set log data in a single
>   table (Log Entries)?

In all likeliehood yes, the exception would be if the number of rows grew to adversely impact response times.

> Should the Exercise Type and Equipment tables be separate or just
>   columns in the Exercise Table? Same goes for Workout Type

They should be separate to reduce unnecessary duplication and issue e.g. if you were to change a type or and equipment then you'd have to apply that change to all rows in the exercise table with a separate table you just have to make the one change.

> Would this be a good approach in terms of performance/usability?

With the exception of the Log table (as it stands including wanting the date) then it appears to be a good and efficient approach. The Log table isn't needed as the Log Entries table has a column for the date time (So in response to the comment yes it would be better to make use of the date/time in the Log Entries and to do away with the log table).

Comment: I imagine a regular user would create ~100 entries per week in the Log Entries table - would this likely affect performance over the course of a few years? If so would a solution be to create a new log entry table every time it reaches a certain size?

Comment: @SQLol even at 100 a day even an hour it shouldn't be problem for many years. A 100000 rows wouldn't be considered large and should be easily managed nowadays.